# Rails route redirect if parameter is set with questionmark

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to redirect if a certain parameter is set in the url with the question-mark.

I tried the following:

```
get "/?cat=:cat", to: redirect("/")
get "?cat=:cat", to: redirect("/")
get ":cat", to: redirect("/")
```

But none of these work.. Searching didn't really get me anywhere either..

Comment: Are you saying that you want to issue a 301 redirect if a query string is present?

Comment: Yes. It's for SEO purposes.. Is it a bad idea?

Comment: Searching 'query string' got me right to what I need.. Thanks!

Comment: please write an answer to your question or delete it right away

Comment: Well, it's unnecessary at the least, and the redirect is probably worse for you SEO-wise.

Comment: I don't understand. Wordpress for example uses query-strings for displaying different pages by default. How can it be unnecessary, or worse for SEO? If `cat=6` was the Contact-page and suddenly it's the Home-page, wouldn't search engines be confused? I don't see the problem.. Could you maybe point me to some information about this 'bad practice'? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get "/" => redirect("/"), constraints: lambda{ |req| req.params[:cat].eql? "6" }
```